# CIDR Overlap Impossible Results Python

Tags: python, networking, cidr

I can't explain the following. Cloudformation told me my subnets overlapped. I couldn't believe it so I tested it in python. This is what I get:

```py
In [0]: import ipaddr

In [12]: ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.128.0/23').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.136.0/20'))
Out[12]: True

In [18]: ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.128.0/23').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.144.0/20'))
Out[18]: False

In [19]: ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.128.0/23').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.143.0/20'))
Out[19]: True
```

```py
In [0]: import ipaddr

In [20]: ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.134.0/23').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.136.0/20'))
Out[20]: True

In [22]: ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.134.0/23').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.144.0/20'))
Out[22]: False

In [23]: ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.134.0/23').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('10.0.143.0/20'))
Out[23]: True
```

This simply can't be the case, can it? First off, 10.0.134.0/23 should have its last IP address at 10.0.135.255. So it shouldn't overlap with 10.0.136.0/20.

Similarly, though, why should both CIDR's end at 10.0.144.0 according to this program?

Is the program simply unreliable?

Note: The new library `ipaddress` seems to agree.

Comment: I get an error when I try to create `ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.136.0/20')`

Comment: If you do a bitwise `AND` on an address with the mask, you get the network address. Remember that IP addresses are unsigned integers. Your example of `10.0.136.0/20` is `167,806,976` (decimal), and a 20-bit mask is `4,294,963,200` (decimal). A bitwise `AND` gives you `167,804,928`, which is different than your original address, so your original address is _not_ a network address; it is a host address in the network. See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for IPv4 calculation.

Answer (score 0):

`10.0.136.0` is not the beginning of a `/20` network. It's in the middle of the network `10.0.128.0/20`, which ranges from `10.0.128.0` to `10.0.143.255`. This obviously overlaps with `10.0.134.0/23`.

The new `ipaddress` module checks for this. `ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.136.0/20')` raises an exception:

> ValueError: 10.0.136.0/20 has host bits set

You can suppress the check with the `strict=False` option, but then you won't be warned about the problem. But if you look at the value returned, you'll see where the address range starts.

```
>>> print(ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.136.0/20', strict=False))
10.0.128.0/20
```

A `/20` network has a third octet that's a multiple of 16.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I thought you could make anything /20 and it would start from there.

Comment: No, that's not how CIDR works. `/20` means that all the addresses in the network have the same first 20 bits.